# Where can I find the tax_label value through BigCommerce API?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm currently migrating a website from BigCommerce Stencil to Gatsby and the Stencil version uses the [catalog price object](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/stencil-object-model-reference/stencil-objects/common-objects/catalog-price) to check for `product.price.with_tax` and fetch `product.price.tax_label` in case the price excludes tax.

On the backend, the option is set on Store Setup > Tax > Manual Tax > Edit > Configure Tax Options > Tax Label.

I managed to find `is_price_entered_with_tax` on the [API Reference](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/store/store-information-api/store-information-reference/getstore) but the only mention to the tax_label value is on the catalog price object.

Is there any way to access that value using v2 or v3 APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an interesting project!

You can access the Tax Label value using the [server-to-server Checkout API](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-reference/cart-checkout/server-server-checkout-api/checkout/checkoutsbycheckoutidget). It will be surfaced as the "name" property in the taxes array:

```
"taxes": [
            {
                "name": "This is the Tax Label",
                "amount": 1.50
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Hey Karen, thank you for replying. I'm trying to display the tax label on a product page. The data is available on stencil product object but not on the product API, nor on the store metadata API. At that point in time I don't have a checkout ID I could use with the checkout API.

Comment: That's correct, @GabrielVilchesAlves--our product and store information APIs don't support the tax_label field. Mind if I ask your use case for displaying the tax label on the product page?

Comment: Well, not at all. I'm just trying to display in more explicit terms what taxes would apply to the product. <>$29,99, Excl: {tax_label}</>, for example. Current version displays {{product.price.with_tax.formatted}}, Excl: {{product.price.tax_label}}.

Comment: I see--thanks for the additional info! If I understand correctly, you would prefer to pull the tax label through the API so the tax_label value dynamically reflects whatever the store owner has entered in the control panel, instead of hard coding something like "Excluding Sales Tax"?

Comment: exactly! This is currently possible using the price object in stencil but only present on the checkout API, not "globally" available.